# Setting cookies in Angular 1.3.x

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I need to store cookies in an angular 1.3.x project with an expiration date. However the ng-Cookies for 1.3.x seem very limited in functionality and I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Unfortunately upgrading versions of Angular is not an option at the moment, so I am stuck in this version.

How would I set a cookie in angular 1.3.x with an expiration date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

> https://github.com/ivpusic/angular-cookie

And set the "expires:" object option with the int value (this value must be a DAY in wich the cookie will expire)

This will work for Angular 1.3 but is unnecessary for 1.4 and later versions.